# Migrate from unencrypted realm to encrypted realm Android

Tags: android, realm

We have a version of app which uses realm but its not encrypted and its been released. But now we want to encrypt realm file with the latest version. so in the Application class, onCreate(), I call the below method.

```
fun setRealmMigrationConfiguration() {
    realmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .migration(RealmMigrationClass())
            .build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration)

    keyStore.load(null)
    val realmKey = "realmKey"


    val realmKeyFile = File("${this.filesDir}/$realmKey")

    if(keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
        if(!realmKeyFile.exists()) {
            keyStore.deleteEntry(alias)
        }
    }

    val encryptedRealmFileName = "default.realm.enc"

    if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {

        //Generates key pair in key store
        generateKeyPairInKeyStore(alias)

        val privateKeyEntry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null) as KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry
        val publicKey = privateKeyEntry.certificate.publicKey

        val key = generateKey()

        val encryptedKey = encryptKey(publicKey,key)

        realmKeyFile.writeBytes(encryptedKey)

        val unencryptedRealm = File("${this.filesDir}/default.realm")
        val encryptedRealm = File("${this.filesDir}/$encryptedRealmFileName")


        if (unencryptedRealm.exists() && !encryptedRealm.exists()) {
            val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(encryptedRealm, key)
            realm.close()

            Realm.removeDefaultConfiguration()
        }

        realmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                                    .schemaVersion(1)
                                    .migration(RealmMigrationClass())
                                    .name(encryptedRealmFileName)
                                    .encryptionKey(key)
                                    .build()

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration)

    } else {
        val privateKeyEntry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null) as KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry
        val privateKey = privateKeyEntry.privateKey

        val keyFile = realmKeyFile.readBytes()
        val buffer = decryptKey(privateKey,keyFile)

        realmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(RealmMigrationClass())
                .name(encryptedRealmFileName)
                .encryptionKey(buffer)
                .build()

        Realm.removeDefaultConfiguration()
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration)

        info { "File =>${realmConfiguration?.path}" }
    }
}
```

But when the app is updated from old version to new version, I am getting below exception. Its not able to decrypt the already encrypted file. I made sure that the keys are correct and the file name given in the RealmConfiguration is correct.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Argument: Invalid format of Realm file.
at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.createNativeWithImplicitTransactions(Native Method)
at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.<init>(SharedGroup.java:64)
at io.realm.internal.s.<init>(SharedGroupManager.java:49)
at io.realm.a.<init>(BaseRealm.java:79)
at io.realm.r.<init>(Realm.java:138)
at io.realm.r.b(Realm.java:248)
at io.realm.r.a(Realm.java:228)
at io.realm.u.a(RealmCache.java:126)
at io.realm.r.m(Realm.java:174)
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong here. Can someone point out whats going wrong here?

I have printed the key (byte array) used to encrypt the realm file and decrypt the realm file. Its exactly the same

Comment: Are `.encryptionKey(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512").digest(key)` and `val key = generateKey()` the exact the same `byte[64]`? If the key is wrong, "Invalid format" exception might be thrown.

Comment: @beeender Actually, this is the first time I am encrypting the realm file from unencrypted one. So only one is key is used. The key is not restored from key store to decrypt the key. I have made some changes to the code. Will update the message

Comment: @beeender so how should I go about this?

Comment: I mean, the `key`in  `realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(encryptedRealm, key)` should be exact the same `byte[64]` with the one you use to build the `RealmConfiguration`. But from the source code you provided, I don't think they are the same. Maybe you can do some debugging to check it?

Comment: @beeender Correct. Thanks for your time

Comment: @beeender Can you pls explain why I could not decrypt the file?

Comment: `realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(encryptedRealm, key)` key here is used to encrypt the db, and to open this encrypted db you need the same key (same `byte[64]`) in the `RealmConfiguration` to decrypt it. So you still cannot decrypt the db? Are you sure the keys are same?

Comment: `keyStore.deleteEntry(alias)` will this be called every time which means a new key is generated no matter the file is encrypted or not? If you can make a minimal project which can reproduce the problem, we can help to debug a bit. to help@realm.io if you want to share it privately.

Comment: Sorry I found the issue. Thanks @beeender.